# Self-variating array size in openCV tracking program

Tags: python, arrays, opencv

So, for a school project i have to create an app that would make a tatoo appear on your arm. 
At the moment openCV uses the color of the skin to detect which part of the image is skin.

My problem is this one: on the last step of the code, where the mask with the tattoo is merged to the video feed, the size of the array changes

```
        #attempt to save the ROI coordinates
        fy1=y1
        fy2=y1+tatHeight
        fx1=x1
        fx2=x1+tatWidth

        #create a ROI mask
        roi = frame[fy1:fy2,fx1:fx2]

        #merge the roi mask with the tatoo and the inverted tatoo masks
        roi_bg = cv2.bitwise_and(roi,roi,mask = mask2inv)
        roi_fg = cv2.bitwise_and(tatoo,tatoo,mask = mask2)



        #merge the background and foreground ROI masks
        dst = cv2.add(roi_bg,roi_fg)



        # add the merged mask to the video feed
        roiColor[fy1:fy2,fx1:fx2]=dst #the problem is here
```

I get this error

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (33,2,3) into shape (0,0,3)
```

Could someone help me figure out why the value of fx and fy change?

You can find the repo with the full code [here](https://github.com/KB1395/TattooApplier)

Thanks to anyone that can help

EDIT : [This](https://sublimerobots.com/2015/02/dancing-mustaches/) is the website where I found some inspiration for my code

EDIT 2: Here is the code

```
    # USAGE
# python ball_tracking.py --video ball_tracking_example.mp4
# python ball_tracking.py

# import the necessary packages
from collections import deque
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import cv2

#load tatoo image
imgTatoo=cv2.imread('mustache.png',-1)
tatMask=imgTatoo[:,:,3]
#create a mask from the image
invTatMask=cv2.bitwise_not(tatMask)
imgTatoo=imgTatoo[:,:,0:3]
#define original sizes for the tatoo
tatOrigHeight,tatOrigWidth = imgTatoo.shape[:2]


# construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-v", "--video",
    help="path to the (optional) video file")
ap.add_argument("-b", "--buffer", type=int, default=64,
    help="max buffer size")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# define the lower and upper boundaries of the "green"
# ball in the HSV color space, then initialize the
# list of tracked points
greenLower = (0, 0, 73)
greenUpper = (35, 93, 255)
pts = deque(maxlen=args["buffer"])

# if a video path was not supplied, grab the reference
# to the webcam
if not args.get("video", False):
    camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# otherwise, grab a reference to the video file
else:
    camera = cv2.VideoCapture(args["video"])

# keep looping
while True:
    # grab the current frame
    (grabbed, frame) = camera.read()

    # if we are viewing a video and we did not grab a frame,
    # then we have reached the end of the video
    if args.get("video") and not grabbed:
        break

    # resize the frame, blur it, and convert it to the HSV
    # color space
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=600)
    frame = cv2.bilateralFilter(frame, 11, 17, 17)
    # blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame, (11, 11), 0)
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # construct a mask for the color "green", then perform
    # a series of dilations and erosions to remove any small
    # blobs left in the mask
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, greenLower, greenUpper)
    mask = cv2.erode(mask, None, iterations=2)
    mask = cv2.dilate(mask, None, iterations=2)

    # find contours in the mask and initialize the current
    # (x, y) center of the ball
    cnts = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
        cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]
    center = None



    # only proceed if at least one contour was found
    if len(cnts) > 0:
        # find the largest contour in the mask, then use
        # it to compute the minimum enclosing circle and
        # centroid
        c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
        ((x, y), radius) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
        M = cv2.moments(c)
        center = (int(M["m10"] / M["m00"]), int(M["m01"] / M["m00"]))

        # only proceed if the radius meets a minimum size
        if radius > 10:
            #draw contour of desired shape
            cv2.drawContours( frame, c, -1, (239, 0, 0),6 )
            #create the smallest box containing that contour
            rect = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
            box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
            box = np.int0(box)
            #draw the box
            cv2.drawContours(frame,[box],0,(0,0,255),2)
            #Save the box parameters (center,height,width and angle)
            areaCenter=rect[0]
            areaX,areaY=int(areaCenter[0]),int(areaCenter[1])
            areaSize=rect[1]
            areaHeight=int(areaSize[0])
            areaWidth=int(areaSize[1])
            areaAngle=rect[2]
            #define the tattoo size
            tatWidth=int(0.2*areaWidth)
            tatHeight=tatWidth * tatOrigHeight // tatOrigWidth

            #face = cv2.rectangle(frame,(areaX-areaWidth//4,areaY-areaHeight//4),(areaX+areaWidth//4,areaY+areaHeight//4),(255,0,0),2)

            #roiGray=gray[areaY-areaHeight//2:areaY+areaHeight//2, areaX-areaWidth//2:areaX+areaWidth//2]

            #create a mask from the video feed with the size of the region of interest (box created before)
            roiColor=frame[areaY-areaHeight//2:areaY+areaHeight//2, areaX-areaWidth//2:areaX+areaWidth//2]

            # print(areaX,areaY,areaWidth,areaHeight)
            # print(tatWidth,tatHeight)

            # save the center of the region of interest (ROI)
            x1 = areaX - (tatWidth//2)
            x2 = areaX + (tatWidth//2)
            y1 = areaY - (tatHeight//2)
            y2 = areaY + (tatHeight//2)

            # protect from wierd center coordinates (outside of the frame)
            if x1 < 0:
                x1 = 0
            if y1 < 0:
                y1 = 0
            if x2 > areaWidth:
                x2 = areaWidth
            if y2 > areaHeight:
                y2 = areaHeight
            print(x1,x2,y1,y2)

            # resize the tattoo to match the ROI size
            tatHeight=tatWidth * tatOrigHeight // tatOrigWidth
            tatWidth=x2-x1

            # protect from wierd (negative) tatoo sizes
            if tatHeight<=0:
                tatHeight=1
            if tatWidth<=0:
                tatWidth=2
            print(tatHeight)
            print(tatWidth)

            # resize all the masks to the same size in order to merge them
            tatoo=cv2.resize(imgTatoo,(tatWidth,tatHeight),interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
            mask2=cv2.resize(tatMask,(tatWidth,tatHeight),interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
            mask2inv=cv2.resize(invTatMask,(tatWidth,tatHeight),interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)


            print(mask2inv.shape)

            #attempt to save the ROI coordinates
            fy1=y1
            fy2=y1+tatHeight
            fx1=x1
            fx2=x1+tatWidth

            #create a ROI mask
            roi = frame[fy1:fy2,fx1:fx2]
            print(roi.shape)

            #merge the roi mask with the tatoo and the inverted tatoo masks
            roi_bg = cv2.bitwise_and(roi,roi,mask = mask2inv)
            roi_fg = cv2.bitwise_and(tatoo,tatoo,mask = mask2)

            print(roi_bg.shape,roi_fg.shape)

            #merge the background and foreground ROI masks
            dst = cv2.add(roi_bg,roi_fg)

            print("dst: ",dst.shape)
            print("roi: ",roiColor.shape)
            print(fy1,fy2,fy2-fy1)
            print(fx1,fx2,fx2-fx1)

            # add the merged mask to the video feed
            roiColor[fy1:fy2,fx1:fx2]=dst


    # show the frame to our screen
    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    # if the 'q' key is pressed, stop the loop
    if key == ord("q"):
        break

# cleanup the camera and close any open windows
camera.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: It looks like you need to convolve your image with the tatoo mask...

Comment: Before `roiColor[fy1:fy2,fx1:fx2]=dst`, print the dimension of LHS and RHS matrix as: `print roiColor.shape, dst.shape`. One of these matrices seems to be of size zero, since `roiColor` is not being mentioned in this code snippet you need to track the source of this matrix and debug why it could be empty.

Comment: That's what I did and i got this `dst: (33, 2, 3) roi: (156, 278, 3)  Traceback (most recent call last): File ".\ball_tracking.py", line 181, in <module> roiColor[fy1:fy2,fx1:fx2]=dst ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (33,2,3) into shape (0,0,3) `

Comment: What is roiColor? And do the specified co-ordinates fit entirely inside the frame? If you're going over the edge, it's not going to work.

Comment: I'll paste the whole code in the original post

Comment: @TouchTheFishy No, posting all that code is not what you ought to do. You're supposed to include a [mcve].-- the smallest program that others can just copy and without any modifications reproduce the problem in question. This keeps the questions concise (remember this is a Q&A site, not a helpdesk), and more importantly, it's a major step on the way to isolating and then solving the problem.

Comment: The problem is that `roiColor` is already a subregion of `frame`, yet you use the same offsets for both. Since `roiColor` is smaller, you go out of bounds and `roiColor[fy1:fy2,fx1:fx2]` ends up a 0x0 array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so thanks to Dan Masek, if solved the problem by bypassing the roiColor that was useless with the following line:

```
frame[fy1:fy2,fx1:fx2]=dst
```

In order to be sure that the area that I want can be included in the original image.